# IndexedDB - DataError: Data provided to an operation does not meet requirements

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I've looked at other similar questions. My case is different because I am inserting simple json objects with no keys, no auto increment.

Here's the part that does the insert:

```
function insertInto(model, data, successCallback) {
    console.log("inserting into model "+model); 
    var transaction = db.transaction([model], IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE || 'readwrite');
    var store, i, request;
    var total = data.length;

    function successCallbackInner() {
        total = total - 1;
        if (total === 0) {
            successCallback();
        }
    }
    transaction.onerror = indexedDBError;
    store = transaction.objectStore(model);
    for (i in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            console.log(data[i]);
            request = store.add(data[i]);
            request.onsuccess = successCallbackInner;
            request.onerror = indexedDBError;
        }
    }
}
```

The error is `DataError: Data provided to an operation does not meet requirements.`

When I log the data I'm trying to insert it confirms my object is a simple object with three string parameters: `Object { cooked="well done",  cheese="provolone",  toasted="no"}`

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/neu7wa5n/) with the full testing code.

Any and all suggestions are appreciated. Even "try this" replies. I've been trying to figure this out since yesterday morning.

Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you try it in Chrome you'll see a more informative error:

> DataError: Failed to execute 'add' on 'IDBObjectStore': The object store uses out-of-line keys and has no key generator and the key parameter was not provided.

In the jsfiddle, your object stores are being created with `db.createObjectStore(modelData[i].name, {autoIncrement: false});` which means (1) there is no key path (`keyPath` option not present), and (2) there is no key generator (`autoIncrement` option is false). That means that (1) the keys aren't pulled from the value, and (2) the store won't generate keys for you. So you need to specify keys when calling `add()` or you'll get that exception.

A few examples:

```
// out-of-line keys, no key generator
var s1 = db.createObjectStore('s1');
s1.add(value, "my_key"); // key will be "my_key"

// out-of-line keys, key generator
var s2 = db.createObjectStore('s2', {autoIncrement: true});
s2.add(value); // key will be 1
s2.add(value, 123); // key will be 123
s2.add(value); // key will be 124

// in-line keys, no key generator
var s3 = db.createObjectStore('s3', {keyPath: 'id'});
s3.add({id: 123}); // key will be 123

// in-line keys, key generator
var s4 = db.createObjectStore('s4', {keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true});
s4.add({}); // key will be 1 (and inserted into record)
s4.add({id: 123}); // key will be 123
s4.add({}); // key will be 124 (and inserted into record)
```

Cases not shown would throw a `DataError` exception.

Comment: Awesome! i didn't  realize the key was required... can't wait to implement this tomorrow.. note to self: https://jsfiddle.net/neu7wa5n/1/

Comment: Made me realize that `store.add(value, key)` fails when when a keyPath exists in the object store because `key is pulled from value if keyPath is set`. So the key existing in the value is enough. Many thanks @joshua-bell !!!

Comment: But how can the key be pulled from the data if it is auto generated? That makes no sense.

Comment: Re: Mike's question -  If there's a key path (in-line keys) then the key will only be generated if it can't be pulled out. See the "in-line keys, key generator" cases - if the key is present in the record, the generator is not used.