# Error while adding new record without explicit key (using auto inc key instead)

Tags: indexeddb

Using the [idb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/idb) package I'm trying to add new records to my application DB. The object store is created like this:

```js
const dbEditorStore = db.createObjectStore("myStore",
    { keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true });
dbEditorStore.createIndex("resultIndex", "resultId", { unique: false });
    dbEditorStore.createIndex("tabIndex", "tabId", { unique: false });
```

When I now try to add new data, without explicitly giving a key I get the error

> ConstraintError: Key already exists in the object store.

Here's how I add the data (note the missing key parameter):

```js
await db.add("myStore", data);
```

which confuses me as I expect that for an auto increment key I don't have to specify anything and IndexedDB would handle that automatically.

What is wrong here and what is the correct way to add data in this scenario?

Further info: when I specify the key name in the `add` call I get a different error:

> DataError: Failed to execute 'add' on 'IDBObjectStore': The object store uses in-line keys and the key parameter was provided.

Answer (score 1):

An apparently unrelated answer about [unmet conditions when inserting data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016862/indexeddb-dataerror-data-provided-to-an-operation-does-not-meet-requirements) gave me the ultimate idea what was wrong. When specifying the `keyPath` value no separate primary key is created, but the field given in the key path is used for the primary key (inline key). This aspect is badly described in [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Basic_Terminology#key_path):

> **key path**
> Defines where the browser should extract the key from in the object store or index. A valid key path can include one of the following: an empty string, a JavaScript identifier, or multiple JavaScript identifiers separated by periods or an array containing any of those. It cannot include spaces.

What is "the key" and how can a key be extracted from an object store?

Anyway, the solution here is to not specify a key at all:

```js
const dbEditorStore = db.createObjectStore("myStore", { autoIncrement: true });
```

but only the key generator (`autoIncrement`). I assumed the value `keyPath` would be an automatic value (since it cannot be automatically changed, if it were referring to a field in the data).

Comment: A pull request with a patch to the https://github.com/mdn/content/blob/main/files/en-us/web/api/indexeddb_api/basic_terminology/index.md file would be very welcome — or short of that, raising an issue at https://github.com/mdn/content/issues/new/choose describing this shortcoming in the current article would be great too.