# How to fill a DateTime column in indexed db using JsStore

Tags: javascript, datetime, indexeddb

Here is my table :

```js
{
  name : "TEST",
  columns : {
    K_A : {dataType : "string"},
    DT_VAL : {dataType : "date_time"},
    DT_SENT : {dataType : "date_time"},
    pk: {
      primaryKey: true,
      keyPath: ['K_A', 'DT_VAL']
    },
    sent: {
      keyPath : ["DT_SENT"]
    }               
  }
}
```

I'm totally unable to insert a record into this table. I have no idea of the format for a Datetime column. I tried almost all solutions :new Date(); Date.now(), new Date().toISOString(), new Date().toGMTString(), new Date().toUTCString(), new Date().toString().... nothing works.

```js
dt=new Date().toISOString();
record={
  K_A:"A", 
  DT_VAL: dt,
  DT_SENT: dt 
};
    
// Using jsStore
db.connection.insert({
  into: "TEST",
  upsert:true
  values : record,
  validation: false
});
```

Whatever I try, I get this :

> Uncaught (in promise)
> Object { message: "Data provided to an operation does not meet requirements.", type: "DataError" }

EDIT : Final asynchronous JS code slipped out of the code section and correction about keyPath.

Comment: The code provided has no mention of promises. Please update the code to be a [mcve]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016862/indexeddb-dataerror-data-provided-to-an-operation-does-not-meet-requirements

Comment: @evolutionxbox : Sorry, the following js slipped out of the code section : 

"// Using jsStore db.connection.insert({ into: "TEST", upsert:true values : record, validation: false});", it's this asynchronous call that generates the error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem comes from the use of keypath.

(Please note that in my post the keypath was ['K_A', 'DT_TRACE'] but in my code it was correct: ['K_A', 'DT_VAL'], just a copy/cut error while posting)

Anyway removing the keypath and using new Date() works.

```
    {
        name : "TEST",
        columns : {
            K_A : {primaryKey: true, dataType : "string"},
            DT_VAL : {primaryKey: true, dataType : "date_time"},
            DT_SENT : {dataType : "date_time"},
        }
    }

    record={ K_A:"A", 
             DT_VAL: new Date(),
            DT_SENT: new Date() 
            };
   // Using jsStore 
   db.connection.insert({ into: "TEST", upsert:true values : record, validation: false});
```